# Is it possible to replace initial text by a figure in embedded 3D object in pdf?

Tags: movie15

Is it possible to replace initial legend ("text=(3Dobject.u3d),") with a Figure?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[3D]{movie15}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}

\begin{document}

\includemovie[
    poster,
    toolbar, %same as `controls'

label=3Dobject.u3d,

text=(3Dobject.u3d),

3Daac=60.000000, 3Droll=0.000000, 3Dc2c=-2.199000 -7.335000 -0.499800, 3Droo=7.673827, 3Dcoo=-2.198981 1.693831 0.499835,
    3Dlights=CAD,
]{\linewidth}{\linewidth}{3Dobject.u3d}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pkg `media9` should be preferred over `movie15`.

Inserting an image file to be shown instead of the inactive 3D object is easy. Using [`dice.u3d`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/doc/files/dice.u3d) from pkg `media9`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
  \includemedia[
    3Droo=27,
    3Dtoolbar
  ]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}}{dice.u3d}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... It works. With the Movie15 i tried something similar but it dis not work. Strange that miktex does not install all dependencies when it install the package media9. Need to install manually the l3backend...